# AVAssetWriter frame rate slightly off

Tags: macos, video, encoding, avasset

I'm trying to use the OSX AVAsset classes to read in video frames from a movie file, adjust the coloring, then write them out to a new movie file. I've got it all working except, for some weird reason, while I'm reading in a video that plays at 29.97 frames per second (according to the inspector in Final Cut Pro X), the output video is listed as being 30 frames per second even. This small discrepancy, among other problems, makes it impossible for me to swap the two video files in a Final Cut project.

I'm using the exact timing information from the decoded/input frames when doing my writing/encoding. Here's the relevant code below.

When reading/decoding a frame:

```
CMSampleBufferRef videoSampleBuffer = [assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];  
if (videoSampleBuffer == NULL)  
  return false;  

CMSampleTimingInfo myTiming;  
CMSampleBufferGetSampleTimingInfo(videoSampleBuffer, 0, &myTiming);  
frameInfo->frameTimeValue = myTiming.presentationTimeStamp.value;  
frameInfo->frameTimeScale = myTiming.presentationTimeStamp.timescale;
```

When writing/encoding the modified frame:

```
CMTime myTime = CMTimeMake(frameInfo->frameTimeValue, frameInfo->frameTimeScale);  
[pixelBufferAdapter appendPixelBuffer:pixelsBuffer withPresentationTime:myTime];
```

Ideas? The time scale values do seem to indicate the video should be encoding at 29.97 fps (it has frameTimeValue values of 1001 and 2002, etc, with frameTimeScale of 30000). Even if I manually increase the frameTimeValue by like 1030 for each frame rather than 1001, it still pegs the video to 30 fps. Once I crank it to like 1050 I start getting an accurate framerate of like 28.75 or whatever it works out to.

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem - you have to manually set the time scale of the AVAssetWriterInput before you add any frames. Otherwise it assumes some time scale that might not be compatible with the time scale of the frames you're adding, causing rounding errors and creating the wrong frame rate.

```
assetWriterInputVideo.mediaTimeScale = 30000;
```

Comment: This fixed a stutter that would occur when exporting 60fps video. I would recommend you also set the AVAssetWriter movieTimeScale variable to the same value. Documentation: `In order to avoid inconsistencies between the track's media time scale and the result's media time scale (see AVAssetWriter property movieTimeScale ) both should be set to equal or compatible values.` If you are starting with an AVAsset you can get the naturalTimeScale from the AVAssetTrack. Thank you!